# Can this random glitching face color behavior be fixed in Eevee and Vieport? Blender 3.4

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, random

I want to make random color depending on face position in Blender 3.4. I use geometry nodes to save attributes and use them in my shader. I get the following behavior depending on the renderer

**Vieport**
[image: Vieport]
**Cycles**
[image: Cycles]
**Eevee**
[image: Eevee]
**Shader**
[image: Shader]
**GeoNodes**
[image: GeoNodes]

Is it possible to get not glitching colors in Eevee (Vieport as well)? The setup seems to kind of work but not very well.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/white_noise.html), bad precision may have significant impact on the output of *White Noise* node. Cycles has better precision, so you don't face errors then using it. Try to eliminate this bias by rounding the value to an acceptable accuracy, using *Vector Math* node:

[image]

Or simply use Noise texture with Perlin noise.

Answer (score -1):

As sometimes happens. As soon as I post the question I got the answer myself.

Seems like White Noise is not working as stable in Eevee as it works in Cycles... Replacing White Noise node with simple Noise Texture solved the problem.